# Save Button works on "default" result set but not on filtered result set

Tags: c#, .net

**Mass Edit**

**The background:**

I have a webpage that has a save button on each data row.

Every time the function AccessRecords is called the first thing it does is `dashboard.Controls.Clear();` where dashboard is my PlaceHolder.

I have an index/counter that is used to identify each row uniquely.

When the save button is created for row 6, it receives the name saveButton6 and stores the recordId in the CommandName property and the tally in the CommandArgument property.

The save then triggers the save command/function and the two stored properties are used to build the query for the SQL procedure.

The illusion that this was working fine existed when the initial load of the screen fetched all the records. I have now switched the initial load to be only active records, and that if you wish to see inactive records you must select that and click the "search" button - which calls the AccessRecords function again but passes in different parameters.

**The problem:**
When I search for inactive records and select a field to change, and then click the save button, on the 6th row for example, it runs the save function not on the current record selected (ID 15), but rather on the record on the initial load that held the position of 6 row (ID 11).

This leads me to believe that when the AccessRecords clears the PlaceHolder and then reestablishes the controls - even though it is updating the data fields correctly, it is not rebuilding the saveButton6, but rather reusing the former saveButton6 (with ID 11 instead of 15).

**Edit** I've done a more thorough clearing of controls, and discovered that the save function is not executed on anything but the default query results.  So if I have 6 active records, I can change their statuses hit the associated save button and their status are saved.  However, when I filter to get the inactive records or all records, as soon as I hit save, first the page reloads - and reloads with default filter settings.  The records revert back to the same records as the original 6 active records (save that the dropdownlists show as selected values those that belonged to the first 6 rows on the search results). Then if I hit save here, it processes the save button as it did on the initial page before doing a search.  Which means, that unless I fix this bug or have the initial view be all records inactive records can never be reactivated.

**Edit - The perceived problem source:**
It appears this might have to do with the event handler issues I have seen others address. Where the pageLoad function executes anytime any other event handler fires.  The order of placement in the code seems irrelevant.

**A Possible Solution:**
One solution I thought of was to have the initial load be blank so no buttons are created.  Then when the search button is selected, the page reloads - but for this to work I would have to store all the selected filter options in the url or in a session variable or some other semi-persistent storage such that they are used on the next load.  This "fix" would be very tedious.

**The Question - edited:**
How do I resolve the loading issue such that the save event fires before the pageLoad event?

**Code Layout**

```
protected void accessRecord()
{
    <logic that determines initial whereClause>
    accessRecord(whereClause)
}
protected void accessRecord(string FilterParam)
{
    <logic that populates dashboard PlaceHolder with query results>
    //also creates buttons per record for record changes
}
protected void filter(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    filter(); //Allows button push in filter div to load dashboard
}
protected void filter()//allows filter to be called in other places to get the current filter settings and load the dashboard
{
    <logic that determines whereClause with user selected filters from a filter div>
    accessRecord(whereClause)
}
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        loadFilterButtonBar();       
        accessRecord();
}
protected void saveChange(object sender,EventArgs e)
{
    //executes SQL queries to save the change made to the record
    <logic for queries>
    filter();

    //Uses LinkButton lb = (LinkButton)sender;
    //     string recordID = (string)lb.CommandName;
    //     string statusDD_ID = (string)lb.CommandArgument;
    //To determine which record to update
}
```

Answer (score 0):

https://www.devu.com/tutorials/cs-asp/articles/lesson-17-page_load-and-page-ispostback

It took me a while to figure out how to do this correctly.  Everytime I've tried ispostback as a condition on load, I would result in a blank screen if I clicked a button - I didn't previously have an else clause.

```
...Page_Load...
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        setInitialFilter();
    }
    else
    {
        HttpContext context = HttpContext.Current;
        string whereClause = (string)(context.Session["whereClause"]);
        accessRecord(whereClause); 
    }

...setInitialFilter()
{
    <logic to set initial conditions>
}

protected void filter()//allows filter to be called in other places to get the current filter settings and load the dashboard
{
    <logic that determines whereClause with user selected filters from a filter div>

    //Added the following two lines
    HttpContext context = HttpContext.Current;
    context.Session["whereClause"] = whereClause;

    accessRecord(whereClause)
}
```